# MVC3 partial view locations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, directory

The view structure in MVC3. It is designed with everything under "shared" to be usable to other folders? What if I want to access views under folders other than "shared"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own view engine that inherits from the default but looks in some additional locations to find the fiew

OR

You can reference the view using a relative URL.